# How to read an array of derived objects from DocumentDB with .NET client

Tags: c#, linq, azure, azure-cosmosdb

So I'm trying to use DocumentDB to store some Entities that contain a list of child components that could be of varying types. A simple example of what I want to store is as follows:

```
public class Component
{
   public string ComponentType { get; set; }
}

public class BudgetComponent: Component
{
   public decimal Budget { get; set; }
}

public class DateRangeComponent: Component
{
   public DateTime Start { get; set; }
   public DateTime End { get; set; }
}

public class Entity
{
   public IEnumerable<Component> Components { get; set; }
}
```

This will save correctly, but when I try to read it I run into problems. If I do this:

```
var docs = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<Entity>(Collection.DocumentsLink);
```

then I end up with an Entity class with a list of `Component` objects; not `BudgetComponent/DateRangeComponent` objects.

This makes sense, since the DB isn't storing any actual type information. I would imagine this is a pretty common scenario though, so I'm hoping there is a solution.

One thing I tried that kinda works is to use the non-generic CreateDocumentQuery call to return a Document object, and manually de-serialize the properties. There are 2 problems with the approach I have been using:

1) It seems I have to get the collection of Components as a collection of `dynamic` objects, which loses type safety, intellisense, etc... and will quickly get messy if the Components have children of their own.

2) Perhaps more significantly, I lose the ability to use Linq for strongly-typed queries against Entity.

So, is there an elegant solution to this problem with DocumentDB?

Comment: Sorry what does LINQ have to do with this?  It's completely agnostic to the storage, even when there is no hard storage (just memory objects).  Did you mean [tag:entity-framework]?  If so take a look at [Implementing Inheritance (EF)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

Comment: I'm referring to the DocumentDB .NET Client that allows for Linq queries that are transformed to database queries (similar to Linq to Entities in EF). i.e. `CreateDocumentQuery<Entity>(Collection.DocumentsLink).Where(e => e.Tenant == "vds");`

I cannot do this if I'm using the non-generic version of `CreateDocumentQuery`, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

If your collection has mixed types in it then this won't work because there is no type information stored (as you correctly stated above).  However, if your collections contain individual types in each collection and you specifically know the type you are retrieving, then this might help you.

First create a repository which takes a generic type and has a static method that accepts the document collection link as a string:

```
    public class DocumentRepository<T> where T : class
    {            
        public static IEnumerable<T> GetDocuments(string docLink)
        {
          //code assumes Client object is instantiated earlier
          var docs = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(docLink).AsEnumerable();

          return docs;
        }
    }
```

Then you can call it from your code like this:

```
    var docs= DocumentRepository<DateRangeComponent>
                          .GetDocuments(Collection.DocumentsLink);
```

Note: the call to .AsEnumerable() in the repository is lazy and won't execute until you enumerate the collection. The .AsEnumerable() is also optional and the CreateDocumentQuery call will instead return an IOrderedQueryable collection which will also execute lazy.  You can alternately use .ToList() to make it execute earlier. Lots of options!

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need it to be a single collection of Entity types, and each Entity contains an embedded list of mixed types. This is something that is apparently on their radar, but they don't expect to implement it anytime soon. So I ended up abandoning DocumentDB and using MongoDB in a set of VMs instead. Mongo's .NET library has built-in support for configuring class maps with discriminators to accomplish this type of thing. I do still lose the ability to use Linq for building queries, but that turned out to be otherwise limited in DocDB anyway, and at least I don't have to deal with `dynamic` objects.